# Regexp substring: Remove eventual left characters?

Tags: regex, substring

I have lines such as those:

```
sa5sdf 54dsafd fdsafara lastword
ffd dfdfsdf,l dsf dsfds 4k6m alsoalastword
fä45 4354'35ä54-ggf.a anotherlastword
verylastword
```

I want to extract the last word to get this:

```
lastword
alsoalastword
anotherlastword
verylastword
```

As you can see, the last word usually is after the last white space. But in all other cases, the word is alone on one line.

How do I achieve this? (In Notepad++'s replace function if that matters)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following regular expression.

```
Find: ^((?!\S+$).)+
Replace: 
         ^^ empty value
```

[**Live Demo**](http://regex101.com/r/yG4iX4/1)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the regex

```
\s\S*$
```

see how matches at http://regex101.com/r/cE6yS6/2

The regex would match space `\s` followed by anything other than space `\S` until the end of the line.

In effect it would extract the last words

```
lastword
alsoalastword
anotherlastword
verylastword
```

Comment: Great! Finally, what do I  type in "Find what:" field and what do i type in the "Replace with:" box, in order to just be left with the lastwords in my open textfile?

Comment: @user689881 you can use this regex in `find what` and in `replace with` you need not give anything(will repalce with null, in effect remove these matched words)

Answer (score 0):

```
^.*[ ]
```

Try this.Replace with `empty string`.See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/tF5fT5/38

`^`=>from start

`.*`=>capture everything

`[]`=>untill last space